# Adding/deleting object properties and removing null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remember open accordions in a custom plugin. The first accordion is open by default, so:

```
var active = [0];
```

I click on accordions and then read from `localStorage` to get the values. Inside my click event:

```
var active = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(outerName)),
    tab = $(this).find('h3').index(ui.tab[0]);

if (tab in active) {
    delete active[tab];
} else {
    active[tab] = tab;
}
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (active[i] == null) {
        active.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
localStorage.setItem(outerName, JSON.stringify(active));
```

This works, except where I remove the first accordion and then click the second and I'll get duplicated values `[1,1]`. I have already removed the null values each time so this is the cause but I don't know how to get the values properly so that if I toggle an accordion it will get removed from the object.

`[0,3]` = Accordion 1 and 4 is open

`[0,1]` = Accordion 1 and 2 is open

Comment: wouldn’t it be easier to use an array with one entry for each accordion and their values set to true/false?

Comment: There are a variable amount of accordions. Anyway I patched my plugin and checked for null so I can replace the values. I'll answer my own question now *sigh!*

Comment: the size of an array is variable too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I patched my plugin to only get the numbers from the active strings, but I also modified my object because it was broken:

```
if (tab in active && active[tab] !== null) {
    delete active[tab];
} else {
    active[tab] = tab;
}
```

I was getting [null,1,null], so now I overwrite the null and just replace it with the value [0,1,null] and only 0 and 1 is read by the plugin.

SO answers my own questions so quickly!